# Design of bias-T (L band,10 MHz,DC)

Tags: rf, inductor, emc, bias

I want to design a bias-T for satellite application where L band RF (950-2150 MHz),10 MHz, and DC will be multiplexed.

I need help in finalizing/selecting the inductor(choke) through which DC (13V/18V,2 amperes) will be passed.

Also what I understood is the inductor must block both L band RF and 10 MHz signal.

Exactly what parameters I should consider while selecting the inductor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The inductor needs to block 10MHz and 950-2150Mhz. To "block" them you want the impedance of the inductor to be much larger than the impedance of the line it T's the DC into. If the line is 50 ohms then you want an inductor of > 500 ohms.

Use ZL = 2 x Pi x Freq x L = 500 Ohms

At 10MHz, ~8uH is 500 Ohms
At 950Mhz, ~84nH is 500 Ohms
At 2150MHz, ~37nH is 500 Ohms

You need a rated current of > 2A and self-resonant frequency (SRF) above each of those frequencies.

From a practical standpoint I don't think you'll find a single inductor of > 8uH with 2A current rating and > 2150MHz SRF. You'll need 2 or 3 inductors in series.

Example:
L1 >= 8uH, Irated >= 2A, SRF >= 10MHz
L2 >= 84nH, Irated >= 2A, SRF >= 950MHz
L3 >= 37nH, Irated >= 2A, SRF >= 2150MHz

You might get away with combining L2 and L3 together. Look at practical inductors that are available on the market and simulate them with an inductor model that takes into account SRF, DC resistance, etc. to see how they perform.

Also note that nothing magical happens at an inductor's SRF. We try to choose an inductor with an SRF well above the frequency of interest but it can be at or slightly below it if need be.

You will also want to look at parallel capacitors in your bias T for similar reasons. One for low frequency and a second for the high band. 2 should be fine.

Comment: You may also try using ferrite beads

Comment: Thanks for a detailed explanation. Does Combining L2 and L3 means 121 nH inductor  having srf more than 2150 MHz wrt example. And parallel capacitors u mentioned,is it for decoupling DC or something else..

Comment: You could use just an inductor over 84nH with I rated > 2A and SRF > 2150MHz.

Comment: On the capacitors, a bias T typically has a DC block, but doesn't have to. That DC blocking cap migh or might not need to pass 10MHz, it depends on what you're doing.

Comment: Ferrite heads are intended to actually convert RF energy into heat. So, if you have RF energy on a bias line somewhere then you can use a ferrite head to dissipate it as heat. For a bias T you really just want to block the RF signal from propagating to the bias line. So you want a good inductor with a high impedance, not with loss.

Comment: Thanks for explaining with nice explanation ....learnt a lot from this.....

Answer (score 1):

You basically need the highest inductance you can get, with the lowest DCR, and with SRF above 2200 MHz.

Most likely you will end up needing to use two or more inductors in series to get really good performance. Possibly you might want to add some large-ish resistors in parallel with these inductors to "de-queue" the circuit. And practically, you will need to basically try a variety of parts from various vendors, considering their parasitic properties, until you find a combination that works well in your application.